# Add columns to SQLite table at runtime with SQLAlchemy (or without)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Basically, I have an existing database with a fixed number of tables that i have created using SQLAlchemy ORM inheriting Base and a list of columnobjects from a "CustomColumn" class I have created.

I am trying to populate my database using values found in some log files. The issue is every once in a while a new key and value are introduced in a log file. The obvious solution is to add that key manually as a column to the table but I'm hoping to automate this whole thing.

Is it possible to, while my python code is running/updating the database, add a new column to the table and have the added column be a permanent feature of the sqlite table and the SQLAlchemy metadata for that table?

This is what I have attempted distilled to what I think is relevant:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, SmallInteger
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

...
# Do a bunch of session.add() for groups of keys:values found in log file
...

# Found a group with a key not in Base.metadata.tables[table_name].columns.keys()

#get rid of any added entries from this log file
session_savepoint.rollback()
# Create new CustomColumn instance
new_column = CustomColumn(new_column_name, new_column_type, classification = "FOO") 
# Alter SQLite table
session.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD {new_column_name} {new_column_type}")
# Add column to metadata
Base.metadata.tables[table_name].append_column(newColumn)
# Add instance of CustomColumn to the set of columns the table inherits
setattr(ColumnSet, new_column_name, new_column)

session.commit()
session.close()

# return a flag indicating this log file should be parsed again
```

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong here would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: "The obvious solution is to add that key manually as a column to the table" - Not necessarily. It would be better to use tables  that can accommodate new values without having to change the structure of those tables.

Comment: @GordThompsonMaybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, I'm very new to working with databases. The only thing I can think of is just having another column called "Extra" or something like that and each entry stores a string containing the extra keys and values separated by some delimiter. That seems pretty inefficient though and sort of negates the usefulness of a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very annoying weekend this is what ended up working:

```
# Found a group with a key not in Base.metadata.tables[table_name].columns.keys()

# revert session since entries will be invalidated by new column
session_savepoint.rollback()

# Create new CustomColumn instance
new_column = CustomColumn(new_column_name, new_column_type, classification = "FOO") 

# Alter SQLite table
session.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD {new_column_name} {new_column_type}")

# Add column to metadata
Base.metadata.tables[table_name].append_column(newColumn)

# ***Add instance of CustomColumn to the table 
table = Base.registry._class_registry[table_name]
setattr(table, new_column_name, new_column)

session.commit()
session.close()
# *** Reload the metadata so updates to Base.registry can be seen
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# return a flag indicating this log file should be parsed again
```

The only two changes made were to

1. add the new `CustomColumn` attribute the table itself instead of the list of columns inherited. If you don't add directly to the table (in my implementation at least) the new column is not passed using the `__mapper__` and ends up being the wrong type and can't be properly read by SQLalchemy orm.
2. Refresh the metadata using `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`

Sometimes the easiest fixes are the most illusive.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically altering your table structures in response to incoming data is a code smell. You should consider designing your tables so that they can capture the values without having to change their structure.

For example, if you have a [log_entry] table

```
[log_entry]

log_id  logged_at            device_id  error_code
------  -------------------  ---------  ----------
     1  2023-11-25 09:39:43  device_1   error_1
```

and then you start getting log entries with an additional attribute "self_repair" you *could* alter the table to add a new column, but a better approach might be to refactor your structure into a parent/child relationship

```
[log_entry]

log_id  logged_at          
------  -------------------
     1  2023-11-25 09:39:43

[log_item]

log_id  type        value
------  ---------   --------
     1  device_id   device_1
     1  error_code  error_1
```

Now when the new log entry arrives you can just add it

```
[log_entry]

log_id  logged_at          
------  -------------------
     1  2023-11-25 09:39:43
     2  2023-11-25 09:51:23
     
     
[log_item]

log_id  type         value
------  ---------    --------
     1  device_id    device_1
     1  error_code   error_1
     2  device_id    device_2
     2  error_code   error_2
     2  self_repair  Success
```

If you need to *present* your values as a single "table" you can pivot them using a query (or a method like pandas' `pivot()`):

```
log_id  logged_at            device_id  error_code  self_repair
------  -------------------  ---------  ----------  -----------
     1  2023-11-25 09:39:43  device_1   error_1                
     2  2023-11-25 09:51:23  device_2   error_2     Success
```

(Pivoted results are sometimes called a "crosstab".)

Comment: Oh wow thanks that's a great suggestion. I was really hoping there would be a way of adding columns but I'm starting to run out of hope of making it work. I'll definitely give this a try instead.